# add location.hash on a jquery search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that will display results

```
$('#searchList li').bind('click', function() {
                        var li = $(this);
                        var li_val = li.text();
                        $('.flagContainer img').attr('class', 'mediumFlag mediumFlag-'+li.attr('data-country-code'));
                        $('.flagContainer').show();
                        el.val(li_val);
                        el.addClass('selected');
                        el.blur();
                        doSearch();
                    });
                } else {
```

i am trying to add

```
$('#searchList li').click(function(){
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    location.hash = hash;
```

so it will display the country name in the location bar, for example www.myexample.com/search#india but what i get with my method is #undefined.
here is all my custom.js (without adding the location hash:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    search_text = $('#quickFilterInput').val();
    $('#quickFilterInput').val(search_text).addClass('defaultValue');
    $('#quickFilterInput').focus(function() {
        if ( $(this).val()==search_text ) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('defaultValue');;
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ( $(this).val()=='' ) {
            $(this).val(search_text).addClass('defaultValue');;
        }
    });
    $('.flagContainer').hide();
    $('#quickFilterInput').bind('keyup', function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        var val = el.val().toLowerCase();
        var w = '';
        if ( val.length > 0 ) {
            el.removeClass('selected');
            $('.flagContainer').hide();
            if ( !el.hasClass('defaultValue') ) {
                var countries = new Array();
                var found = false;
                var query = new Array();
                var phone_val = new Array();
                query.push({'country_lower':{like:val}});
                var current_phone_val = '';
                for ( i = 0; i < val.length; i++ ) {
                    current_phone_val += val[i];
                    if ( db({'country_number':current_phone_val+'*'}).count() > 0 ) {
                        phone_val = new Array();
                        phone_val.push(current_phone_val+'*');
                    }
                }
                if ( phone_val.length > 0 ) {
                    phone_val.push(val);
                    query.push({'country_number':phone_val});
                } else {
                    query.push({'country_number':val});
                }
                db(query).order('title').each( function(r) {
                    if ( $.inArray( r.country, countries ) < 0 ) {
                        found = true;
                        w += '<li data-country-code="'+(r.country_code)+'"><div class="flagContainer"><img src="images/dummy.png" alt="" class="mediumFlag mediumFlag-'+(r.country_code)+'"></div><p>'+(r.country)+"</p></li>"
                        countries.push(r.country);
                    }
                });
                if ( found ) {
                    $('#searchList').html('').html(w);
                    $('#searchList').fadeIn();
                    $('#searchList li').bind('click', function() {
                        var li = $(this);
                        var li_val = li.text();
                        $('.flagContainer img').attr('class', 'mediumFlag mediumFlag-'+li.attr('data-country-code'));
                        $('.flagContainer').show();
                        el.val(li_val);
                        el.addClass('selected');
                        el.blur();
                        doSearch();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#searchList').html('').html('<div class="noMatches"><strong>No countries found.</strong> Please refine your search by country first letters or dialing code</div>');
                    $('#searchList').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        }
    }).bind('blur', function() {        
        $('#searchList').fadeOut();
    });

    $('.clearFilterInput').bind('click', function() {
        clearSearch();
    });
});

function doSearch() {
    var el = $('#quickFilterInput');
    var val = el.val();
    var found = false;
    $('.ratesResults').hide();
    var w = '';
    db({
        'country_lower':{like:val.toLowerCase()}
    }).order('special','title').each( function(r) {
        found = true;
        var title = r.title;
        var special = false;
        if ( r.special == 'a' ) {
            special = true;
        }
        if ( title != val ) {
            title = title.replace(r.country, '');
        }
        w += '<div class="ratesBlock'+(special?' special':'')+'">';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-1">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+title+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem block-2">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4-notax">'+(r.price)+' &pound;</p>';
        w += '<p class="smaller">('+(number_format(r.price_including_tax, 3))+' &pound; incl. VAT)</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-3">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_price)+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-4">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_minutes)+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-5">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_display)+'</p>';
        if ( r.plan_display != r.text_display ) {
            w += '<p class="smaller">'+(r.text_display)+'</p>';
        }
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="buttonContainer noMobile">';
        w += '<a href="'+(r.href)+'" class="btn small secondaryCta" target="_top">';
        w += '<span class="noArrow">buy</span>';
        w += '</a>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '</div>';
    });
    if ( found ) {
        $('.ratesTitle').html('Rates to '+val);
        $('#ratesSearchResults').html(w);
        $('.my_vcust').hide();
        $('.ratesResults').fadeIn();
        $('#ratesSearchResults .ratesBlock.special').each( function() {
            $(this).find('.buttonContainer').css('height', ($(this).height()-10)+'px');
        });
    }
}

function clearSearch() {
    $('.ratesResults').fadeOut();
    $('#ratesSearchResults').html('');
    $('#quickFilterInput').val('').trigger('blur').removeClass('selected');
    $('.flagContainer').hide();
    $('.my_vcust').fadeIn();

}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: you probably want the href from a link inside the `<li>`, try `var hash = $(this).find('a').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting a `li`-element and attach the click event to that. This `li` element obviously doesn't have a href-attribute, and therefore it is `undefined`. Attach it to the underlying a element instead:

```
$('#searchList li a').click(function(){
  //...
});
```

Comment: @koala_dev thanks but i still get  #undefined .@Sumurai8 thanks but if i change to **li a** the script will not display results, also nothing change in the url bar.if i set **var hash = val** in the url bar it will print what i have typed in the search bar.for example **www.myexample.com/search#af** for afganistan in case i searched with **-af-** chars.any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an `a` element under the `li` element?

Comment: no i do not have. in my post 1st post i attached in the end all the javascript. the html file is simple with a **ul** inside a div that has the search/clear button etc. the results (countries) are coming after user types 1st 3 letters, when he select the country i need to update the adress bar with #country_selected_name.thank you!

Comment: Please add the html for one such country search result to your question and leave a comment so I see it. I am now completely clueless why you are trying to use the `href` attribute, as only `a` elements have that.

Comment: i found a simple solution by adding location.hash = li_val; and now it will display the #country_name . I was wondering how it will be also possible if the user point to that hyperlink the results will come automatically for the country. for example : http://example.com/search#usa will go to the search page and will display the results (currently no). can you look on my javascript maybe need an extra fuction?possible in the html file that controls the .js something like **if location.hash = li_val; then do the js fuction that will jquery results? thank you so much!

Comment: On page load, check `location.hash` and if it contains something, load the results via ajax?

Comment: i am a little noobie with ajax, how you think it would be easy to load the results by looking my javascript code?i have managed to check if there is hash with : `if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
       
      // hash found so display the results of the #country
  } else {
      // Load the normal search page
  }`

Comment: This comment section is not meant to have lengthy conversations. I provided you with the name 'ajax', so the logical step would be to lookup 'ajax' or 'jquery ajax'. Find examples if needed. If you don't know how to get a specific part working, try to get as much working around it as you can, read the documentation, and as a last resort ask a new question if needed. Good luck.