# Display jQuery results also when url has hash on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a .js file to control search results with jQuery, basic function that i need to load somehow again (*even when the url bar is www.example.com/search#austria and user navigate on this link should see the results for austria*) is this:

```
function doSearch() {
    var el = $('#quickFilterInput');
    var val = el.val();
    var found = false;
    $('.ratesResults').hide();
    var w = '';
    db({
        'country_lower':{like:val.toLowerCase()}
    }).order('special','title').each( function(r) {
        found = true;
        var title = r.title;
        var special = false;
        if ( r.special == 'a' ) {
            special = true;
        }
        if ( title != val ) {
            title = title.replace(r.country, '');
        }
        w += '<div class="ratesBlock'+(special?' special':'')+'">';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-1">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+title+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem block-2">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4-notax">'+(r.price)+' &pound;</p>';
        w += '<p class="smaller">('+(number_format(r.price_including_tax, 3))+' &pound; incl. VAT)</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-3">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_price)+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-4">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_minutes)+'</p>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="ratesBlockItem ratesBlockTitle block-5">';
        w += '<p class="title-h4">'+(r.plan_display)+'</p>';
        if ( r.plan_display != r.text_display ) {
            w += '<p class="smaller">'+(r.text_display)+'</p>';
        }
        w += '</div>';
        w += '<div class="buttonContainer noMobile">';
        w += '<a href="'+(r.href)+'" class="btn small secondaryCta" target="_top">';
        w += '<span class="noArrow">buy</span>';
        w += '</a>';
        w += '</div>';
        w += '</div>';
    });
    if ( found ) {
        $('.ratesTitle').html('Rates to '+val);
        $('#ratesSearchResults').html(w);
        $('.my_vcust').hide();
        $('.ratesResults').fadeIn();
        $('#ratesSearchResults .ratesBlock.special').each( function() {
            $(this).find('.buttonContainer').css('height', ($(this).height()-10)+'px');
        });
    }
}
```

example of what i mean with adding hash on url bar and also if you reload the page it will display automatic the results is is 
[here](http://www.localphone.com/prices#country,at)

I am trying to add a javascript on the html page that will load the custom.js so it will check if there is country hash in the url (for example www.example.com/search#austria and will display the results for Austria when user navigates through that link)

```
  if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
      alert (hash);
// hash found in the url so let's try somehow to print the results?
doSearch();





  } else {
      // No hash found so let the page show the normal search bar
  }
```

custom.js is bigger, if you need i can paste all (actually is 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810208/add-location-hash-on-a-jquery-search) on the end of my post)

Comment: so what's the issue/question?

Comment: @koala_dev my problem is that i am trying to load the results by the # link but the user did not type any country so the search page loads with #country_name on url but the search bar still has "type country" and of course no results are showing until he manually type 2 letters. I will need to have the jquery country results as hash links.I am sure it is something simple that after lot of reading and testing i will find but just in case you can help it would be much appreciated. Main html has the search elements and loading the custom.js that is taking care of the functions (already posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try populating the input with the hash value before running the search:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    // hash found in the url
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
    $('#quickFilterInput').val(hash);
    doSearch();
} else {
    // No hash found so let the page show the normal search bar
}
```

Comment: aaaamazing!need to study more!thank you so much @koala_dev :)

Comment: only thing now is that the country flag is not displayed on page reload with #country hash.from my custom.js it seems that it will display correct flag only if you type in the search bar and the country will autocomplete. do you have any fast suggestion like + to the code?Otherwise i will try more tommorow, thank you.

Comment: @JohnBrown I assume the flag display happens outside the search function so you need to somehow call that code in your `if(window.location.hash) {..}`